# Rotate CAShapeLayer around center of UIView

Tags: ios, animation, cashapelayer

I am working on animation of CAShapeLayer. I am drawing quarter circle(refer image) which is in 1st quadrant(as per my knowledge). Now I want to rotate it 90 degree so it should fix in 2nd quadrant with animation on single tap gesture. I tried it but it is not fixing into 2nd quadrant. I want to rotate around center of UIView.

Single tap gesture:

```
- (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    CGPoint touchPoint=[gesture locationInView:self];
    NSArray* subLayerArray = [self.layer sublayers];
    for (int i = 0; i < subLayerArray.count; i++) {
        CAShapeLayer* layer = [subLayerArray objectAtIndex:i];

        if(CGPathContainsPoint(layer.path, NULL, touchPoint, NO)){
            CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
            CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, self.bounds.size.width/2-layer.frame.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2-layer.frame.size.height/2, 100, 0*M_PI, M_PI, YES);            
            CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
            anim.path = path;
            anim.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto;
            anim.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
            anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
            anim.removedOnCompletion = NO;
            anim.duration = 10.0;
            [layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@""];
        }
    }
}
```

Drawing Code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, rect.size.width/2, rect.size.height/2, 100, (0), (M_PI_2), NO);
    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, rect.size.width/2, rect.size.height/2, 100-50, (M_PI_2), (0), YES);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
    CAShapeLayer* arcLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc]init];
    arcLayer.path = path;
    arcLayer.frame = CGPathGetPathBoundingBox(path);
    arcLayer.fillColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
    arcLayer.bounds = CGPathGetPathBoundingBox(path);
    [self.layer addSublayer:arcLayer]; 
}
```

and Image:

[image]

Comment: Why not simply animate the `transform.rotation.z` key path  instead?

Comment: i want to rotate around center of UIView instead of it's own centre.

Comment: Rotate a superview with the correct center?

Comment: not superview.Actually i am drawing donut chart with 4-5 levels.so when user taps on any cashapelayer then i want to rotate that level.if i do as you said - "rotate superview" then my all levels will rotate that i dont want.I just want to rotate that level which user has been selected.

Comment: You can always change [the anchor point](http://ronnqvi.st/translate-rotate-translate/) (but there may be side effects such as the view shifting it's position before you get it right) or you can make each view big enough to have it's center in the center of the parent.

Comment: I have only single UIView.In this UIView, i am adding my all cashapelayers.